# "File System Error (-2147416359)". What does that mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: image, windows-10, filesystems, desktop-application

While opening images on Desktop it shows "File System Error (-2147416359)". What does that mean and how to resolve it?, I tried by multiple tool when I tried with Photoscape or Paint it worked properly but When I am trying with Photo Viewer it gives me following error,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL8jA.png

Comment: found when googling : Lemuel Eduarte response https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/file-system-error-2147219196/f4b03e57-84ab-4178-9c54-b978f1d3aa42 which is a link to https://www.tweaking.com/ I know nothing about it, this might help?

Answer (score 6):

File System errors are usually happened by Disk Related Errors which can be due to bad sectors of a disk or anything else related. When you are opening photos, Windows 10 file system error (-2147416359) message may appear. 
To solve this problem just follow the steps below:

1. Press the Win + R keys on your keyboard, to open the Run window. Then, type "services. 
   msc" and hit Enter or press OK. The Services app window is now open.
2. Then find and open "Windows License Manager Service Properties" from there.
3. Startup type: Automatic (Set it Automatic).
4. Click on "Apply" and then "Ok".

Comment: this works like a charm... thanks a lot for the solution. saved me some headache!!

Comment: It is working for me too.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1:You click on the windows icon and search "RUN" and tap on or you use a Shortcut method to open(Windows + R)

2:And now a small pop-up window opens here you search "SERVICES.MSC.

3: Here you navigate to Window Licence Manager and tap on it.

[Read Full Article](https://androidfreeks.com/solved-error-windows-file-system-error-2147416359/)